# Convert char* to string C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I know the starting address of the string(e.g., `char* buf`) and the max length `int l;` of the string(i.e., total number of characters is less than or equal to `l`).

What is the simplest way to get the value of the `string` from the specified memory segment? In other words, how to implement `string retrieveString(char* buf, int l);`.

**EDIT**: The memory is reserved for writing and reading string of variable length. In other words, `int l;`indicates the size of the memory and not the length of the string.

Comment: This is really basic C++. I'll recommend [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Comment: Lest there be any confusion: a `std::string` is *not the same* as a `char[]` string in C++. A `std::string` has a lot of other things to it.

Comment: When you say "max length" do you mean the string might be shorter than that?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes. The memory is reserved for writing and reading string of variable length

Comment: Neither of the 2 existing answers really address that situation. You should edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: And it's a null terminated string?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Up to me how to write the string into the memory. I'm not sure what the typical way is in C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert a char\* to std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195675/convert-a-char-to-stdstring)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
std::string str(buffer, buffer + length);
```

Or, if the string already exists:

```
str.assign(buffer, buffer + length);
```

**Edit:** I'm still not completely sure I understand the question.  But if it's something like what JoshG is suggesting, that you want up to `length` characters, or until a null terminator, whichever comes first, then you can use this:

```
std::string str(buffer, std::find(buffer, buffer + length, '\0'));
```

Comment: Clever use of find! I never thought to use the not-found return value for anything!

Answer (score 25):

```
char *charPtr = "test string";
cout << charPtr << endl;

string str = charPtr;
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: This answer is underrated!

Answer (score 3):

Use the string's constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s,size_type n, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

**EDIT:**

OK, then if the C string length is not given explicitly, use the ctor:

```
basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a few details left out of your explanation, but I will do my best...

If these are NUL-terminated strings or the memory is pre-zeroed, you can just iterate down the length of the memory segment until you hit a NUL (0) character or the maximum length (whichever comes first). Use the string constructor, passing the buffer and the size determined in the previous step.

```
string retrieveString( char* buf, int max ) {

    size_t len = 0;
    while( (len < max) && (buf[ len ] != '\0') ) {
        len++;
    }

    return string( buf, len );

}
```

If the above is not the case, I'm not sure how you determine where a string ends.

Comment: If the given string is guaranteed to have a NULL, all you need is `string(buf)` and you're good.  If it might not, then you have to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str;
char* const s = "test";

str.assign(s);
```

`string& assign (const char* s);  =>  signature FYR`

Reference/s [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/).

Answer (score 0):

Let,

```
char* rw="hii";  //This string is readable and writeable

const char* r="hello"; // This string is only readable
```

we can convert char* or const char* to string with the help of string's constructor.

```
string string_name(parameter);
```

This parameter accepts both char* and const char* types .

Examples:

```
1) string st(rw); 

 Now string 'st', contains "hii"

2) string st(r);

 Now, string 'st' contains "hello".
```

In both the examples, string 'st' is writable and readable.