# How to convert variable number of elements of char array to string

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am using Arduino and receiving a string from serial. I have converted that string into a character array. But I need to convert first 4 or 5 elements of that array back to string. Is there any way to do that?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
String str= String('a[0]');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char* data = ...;
int size = 4;
std::string str(data, size);
```

It's elegant with constructor of std::string.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method of `std::string`.

You can [convetr the `char[]` to an `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195675/convert-a-char-to-stdstring), and then use `substr` to get the sub-string you want.

```
std::string str("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
std::cout << str.substr(0, 9);
```

Output would be:

> The quick

Comment: thank you for your quick response ivan. what im trying to do here is to get a string from serial. if the string starts with COMSTEP, go into the function in which i analyze the rest of the string and tokenize it. string comprise of characters seperated by spaces. do i have to convert the string to char or is there any other way to do that?
P.S: im a noob at arduino. so any help is appreciated

Comment: If you already have a string, there's no need to convert it. Just substring the string you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
char arr[m];
std::string str="";
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str += arr[i];
}
```

I have assumed that you would like to convert first n element of `char aar` into string.

**Or**

```
char* inp = ..;
int size = 4; // int size = 5;
std::string str(inp, size);
```

Comment: You aren't checking bounds. What if `n > m`?

Comment: Also, `std::string` has a constructor for that.

Comment: @IvanRubinson : As OP has mentioned that, he/she would like to convert first 4 or 5 character to string. Hence i assumed that, `m > n`.