# c_str() vs. data() when it comes to return type

Tags: c++, string, c++17, c-str

After C++11, I thought of `c_str()` and `data()` [equivalently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194634/string-c-str-vs-data).

C++17 introduces an overload for the latter, that returns a non-constant pointer ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), which I am not sure if it's updated completely w.r.t. C++17):

```
const CharT* data() const;    (1)   
CharT* data();                (2)   (since C++17)
```

[`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) does only return a constant pointer:

```
const CharT* c_str() const;
```

Why the differentiation of these two methods in C++17, especially when C++11 was the one that made them homogeneous? In other words, why only the one method got an overload, while the other didn't?

Comment: my bet is that is has to do with `c_str` being null terminated, while a `std::string` may contain a null in the middle and I'd expect also `data()` to return just the raw buffer (whether it contains null in the middle or not)

Comment: @user463035818 they both return the same in this bad [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LJo82QEeR7JQwn7i) I made...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Doesn't string::data() Provide a Mutable char\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155390/why-doesnt-stringdata-provide-a-mutable-char)

Comment: @JonathanMee thanks for sharing, but where does this answer my question? From what I can understand from the answers here, "we can only speculate". I don't see how this is a duplicate, but if I am wrong, please let me know. :)

Comment: My understanding was you were asking for the context of the decision why a non-constant `data` was added. I believe that is covered in detail in the other question?

Comment: The TLDR of the other answer is that for [`std::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) to operate on `string` it needs a constant and non-constant `data` method.

Comment: No @JonathanMee, my question is why these methods are not homogeneous, since C++11 moved towards this direction! ;) If I was asking what you thought, then yes, definitely it would have been a duplicate. Now the question is why `data()` got an overload, while `c_str()` did not? I mean we made them homogeneous in C++11, and now we differentiate again, why? These kind of questions are not answered in the duplicate. However, the answers here provide insight to my question!

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm seeing that while the questions are not exactly the same the answer is. It's about [`std::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The new overload was added by [P0272R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r1.html) for C++17. Neither the paper itself nor the links therein discuss why only `data` was given new overloads but `c_str` was not. We can only *speculate* at this point (unless people involved in the discussion chime in), but I'd like to offer the following points for consideration:

- Even just adding the overload to `data` broke some code; keeping this change conservative was a way to minimize negative impact.
- The `c_str` function had so far been entirely identical to `data` and is effectively a "legacy" facility for interfacing code that takes "C string", i.e. an *immutable*, null-terminated char array. Since you can always replace `c_str` by `data`, there's no particular reason to add to this legacy interface.

I realize that the very motivation for P0292R1 was that there do exist legacy APIs that erroneously or for C reasons take only mutable pointers even though they don't mutate. All the same, I suppose we don't want to add more to string's already massive API that absolutely necessary.

One more point: as of C++17 you *are* now [allowed to *write*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2475) to the null terminator, as long as you write the value zero. (Previously, it used to be UB to write anything to the null terminator.) A mutable `c_str` would create yet another entry point into this particular subtlety, and the fewer subtleties we have, the better.

Comment: Yes I couldn't find any relevant information on that document on why `c_str()` didn't get an overload too... Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @gsamaras: No problem -- I added a note about writing to the null terminator.

Comment: Also, I can easily imagine a non-const `c_str()` overload breaking legacy code. Think about calling it on a non-const string, with an auto return type.

Comment: @rustyx: The new `data` overload absolutely *did* break code. We coped, but it's not something you want to do gratuitously.

Comment: @KerrekSB yesterday in my sleep I was thinking about your first bullet. Why the non-const overload would break things? I mean wouldn't it be that where the const is needed, the relevant const overload of the method would be called?

Comment: @gsamaras: right, that's what everyone who proposed this and thought it was trivial was thinking, too. Then real implementers deployed the change to real codebases, and breakages happened. The problem is that real people in real code bases do some pretty weird stuff that you would never have thought of :-S

Comment: Something tells me that I know what I am going to think tonight in my sleep @KerrekSB, what kind of what would break from this overload! But maybe I'll leave it for another question..

Answer (score 23):

The reason why the `data()` member got an overload is explained in [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0272r0.html) paper at open-std.org.

**TL;DR of the paper**: The non-const `.data()` member function for `std::string` was added to improve uniformity in the standard library and to help C++ developers write correct code. It is also convenient when calling a C-library function that doesn't have const qualification on its C-string parameters.

Some relevant passages from the paper:

> **Abstract**
>   Is `std::string`'s lack of a non-const `.data()` member function an oversight or an intentional design based on pre-C++11 `std::string` semantics? In either case, this lack of functionality tempts developers to use unsafe alternatives in several legitimate scenarios. This paper argues for the addition of a non-const `.data()` member function for std::string to improve uniformity in the standard library and to help C++ developers write correct code.
>
> **Use Cases**
>   C libraries occasionally include routines that have char * parameters. One example is the `lpCommandLine` parameter of the `CreateProcess` function in the Windows API. Because the `data()` member of `std::string` is const, it cannot be used to make std::string objects work with the  `lpCommandLine` parameter. Developers are tempted to use `.front()` instead, as in the following example.
>
> ```
> std::string programName;
> // ...
> if( CreateProcess( NULL, &programName.front(), /* etc. */ ) ) {
>   // etc.
> } else {
>   // handle error
> }
> ```
>
> Note that when `programName` is empty, the `programName.front()` expression causes undefined behavior. A temporary empty C-string fixes the bug.
>
> ```
> std::string programName;
> // ...
>
> if( !programName.empty() ) { 
>   char emptyString[] = {'\0'};    
>   if( CreateProcess( NULL, programName.empty() ? emptyString : &programName.front(), /* etc. */ ) ) {
>     // etc.
>   } else {
>     // handle error
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If there were a non-const `.data()` member, as there is with `std::vector`, the correct code would be straightforward.
>
> ```
> std::string programName;
> // ...
> if( !programName.empty() ) {
>   char emptyString[] = {'\0'};
>   if( CreateProcess( NULL, programName.data(), /* etc. */ ) ) {
>     // etc.
>   } else {
>     // handle error
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> A non-const `.data() std::string` member function is also convenient when calling a C-library function that doesn't have const qualification on its C-string parameters. This is common in older codes and those that need to be portable with older C compilers.

Answer (score 5):

It just depends on the semantics of "what you want to do with it". Generally speaking, `std::string` is sometimes used as a buffer vector, i.e., as a replacement to `std::vector<char>`. This can be seen in `boost::asio` often. In other words, it's an array of characters.

`c_str()`: strictly means that you're looking for a null-terminated string. In that sense, you should never modify the data and you should never need the string as a non-const.

`data()`: you may need the information inside the string as buffer data, and even as non-const. You may or may not need to modify the data, which you can do, as long as it doesn't involve changing the length of the string.

Comment: I think the null-termination is a red herring here. Both `c_str` and `data` are absolutely equivalent regarding null termination.

Comment: @KerrekSB is right, after C++11 both methods return a null terminated string.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's not about the null-termination in the sense of whether it exists or not. It's in the sense whether you want "null-terminated string" or "buffer vector", where you don't care about null termination.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Yes, I see your point, but I would somewhat like to dispel the idea that you shouldn't use `data` to request null-termination (which you may or may not want to imply). It's perfectly fine to use `data` for the express purpose of getting a null-terminated string; I would not ask anyone to use `c_str` instead.

Comment: There is some explanation [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14.string).

Comment: @KerrekSB You're right, but keep in mind that C++ is an expressive language, and the text of the code you write should ideally have meaning. Personally I'd consider it bad practice to use `data()` if all you want is a null-terminated string. You wouldn't be helping the guy who reads your code next. It's my opinion, anyway :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB -- yes, both are nul terminated. But that wasn't the case originally. `.data()` returned a pointer to the raw buffer, and that buffer was not required to have a nul terminator. `.c_str()` returned a pointer to a nul-terminated array which, conceivably, could be allocated separately from the buffer itself. No implementation took advantage of this somewhat warty interface: everyone used a nul-terminated buffer, so changing the requirement on `.data()` didn't affect any implementation. If I remember correctly, this was part of making `std::string` safer to use in multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 3):

The two member functions **c_str** and **data** of std::string exist due to the history of the std::string class.

Until C++11, a std::string could have been implemented as copy-on-write. The internal representation did not need any null termination of the stored string. The member function **c_str** made sure the returned string was null terminated. The member function **data** simlpy returned a pointer to the stored string, that was not necessarily null terminated. - To be sure that changes to the string were noticed to enable copy-on-write, both functions needed to return a pointer to const data.

This all changed with C++11 when copy-on-write was no longer allowed for std::string. Since **c_str** was still required to deliver a null terminated string, the null is always appended to the actual stored string. Otherwise a call to **c_str** may need to change the stored data to make the string null terminated which would make **c_str** a non-const function. Since **data** delivers a pointer to the stored string, it usually has the same implementation as **c_str**. Both functions still exists due to backward compatibility.