# Does a function argument const str::string& create a deep copy when the function receives const char*?

Tags: c++, string

Consider a function prototype:

```
void foo(const std::string& str);
```

If I call it with a `const char*` like this:

```
const char buffer[] = "Hello World!";
foo(buffer);
```

will it create a deep copy of the data? Or will it be a shallow copy?

Comment: it should not work.

Comment: You can't pass a `char*` as argument to a function whose parameter is `string&`. This is explained in any beginner level [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: It works with `const` with no warnings (c++14)

Comment: @Kaiyakha It will work with `const string&` because a const lvalue ref can bind to a tempoarary `string` created using the `char*`.

Comment: @JasonLiam will the temporary string have `char*` data as a deep copy?

Comment: @Kaiyakha The constructor `basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` can be used to create the temporary.

Comment: If you care of copy, use `std::string_view`. It should always be used if `const char*` argument is expected.

Comment: Dupe: [convert a char* to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195690/12002570)

Answer (score 1):

> will it create a deep copy of the data? Or will it be a shallow copy?

It will construct a temporary `std::string` object that **deep copies** the characters from the `char[]` into the `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, because there's no constructor for `std::string` that does a *shallow copy*.

Answer (score 0):

Copy or not isn't really meaningful here.

A temporary `std::string` is constructed and passed to the function (as const reference).

(as a result the `buffer` is copied to the `std::string` internal buffer.)

---

you can also pass a `std::string_view`, then there would be no copy.

```
void foo(const std::string_view& str);
```

Comment: I think OP is asking whether `buffer` gets copied into the temporary `std::string` that is constructed?

Comment: @kmoser yes, this is what i'm asking. Precisely, I'm asking if it is a shallow or a deep copy

Comment: @kmoser well that's a strange way to ask does `std::string` constructor make copy.

Answer (score 0):

> will it create a copy of the data?

**The `char*` that you're passing can be used to create a temporary `std::string`** using the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

but the value category of that object will be `rvalue` which cannot bind to an non-const lvalue reference. This means, the given example will not work because a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to an rvalue.

To solve this, you can add a low-level const in the parameter of the function like :

```
//-------vvvvv--------------------->low level const added
void foo(const std::string& str);
```

This works because a const lvalue reference can bind to an rvalue.

Comment: I stood corrected, I added `const`

Comment: @Kaiyakha See my updated answer where a low-level const is added. Also, you should not change your question by taking suggestions given in the answers. That makes the answers pointless.

Comment: I guess I should've been more precise when posting this question. I meant to ask whether `const std::string&` creates a _deep_ or a _shallow_ copy when it receives `const char*` as an argument.

Comment: @Kaiyakha It will just create a copy using the passed `const char*` till the null `'\0'` is found. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195690/12002570) where it says: *"deep copies the character list at `s`"*

Comment: @Kaiyakha you should not make changes to your question that invalidate a reasonable answer.